# Javascript not submitting hidden field value

Tags: javascript, forms

I have basic example of submitting a value to a hidden. But its seems not to want to take my value in my function. Maybe there us something am missing.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function submitForm() {
document.statusform.do.value = "checkstatus";
document.statusform.submit();
}
</script>

<form action="" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="statusform">
<input type="hidden" name="do" id="do" value="">
<input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Resume Request" onClick="submitForm();" /></form>
```

Comment: Don't use 'do' as name, because it a keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, You're wrong in this part:

```
document.statusform.do.value = "checkstatus";
document.statusform.submit();
```

In firefox error console it will be show an error:

> Error: TypeError: document.statusform is undefined

Change that code to:

```
document.forms['statusform'].do.value = "checkstatus";
document.forms['statusform'].submit();
```

Second, remove name attribute from submit button.

Change this part:

```
<input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Resume Request" onClick="submitForm();" /></form>
```

to:

```
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Resume Request" onClick="submitForm();" /></form>
```

Comment: Thank you Iswanto San. Is there a way to store a image hotspot selection to a variable to passed on later in a GET method?

Comment: @saiyan101: you can put the value in hidden field

Comment: I have done that but to no success. this is in my map tags:


`<area shape="poly" coords="472,242,455,234,448,223,460,213,480,197,493,184,504,191,489,231" href="results.php" onclick="alert('<?php echo $_SESSION['map']="NYC"; ?>');submitForm('<?php echo "NYC"; ?>');" />`

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<form action="" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="statusform">
```

to

```
<form action="" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="statusform">
```